# Why My Spi Connection Is Not Getting started?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, spi, circuitpython

Hello Guys I Am New To Embedded & Rasberry PI. So In Order To Understand SPI Connection I Made An PI-PI SPI Setup
 PS. I am Using Two Rasbrry Pi Model 4 B with Raspi OS & i did the followings steps:

### STEP 1:

First I enabled Spi In My Both Rasberry Pi 4 by going through `sudo raspi-config` & Enable `4. SPI Interface`

### STEP 2:

After Did I Made Physical Connection From *1st Rasberry Pi(Master)* To *2nd Rasberry Pi(Slave)* Through Female To Female Jumper
To The  Followings Pin Outs

> 24(CE0-Master) To 24 (CE0-Slave)            // CHIP_SELECT 0 TO 0 (PIN 24)
> 23(S_CLK Master) To 23 (S_CLK Slave)        // SERIAL CLOCK PIN 23
> 21(MISO Master) To 21 (MISO Slave)          // MISO PIN 21
> 19(MOSI Master) To 19 (MOSI Slave)          // MOSI PIN 19

I followed Pin Out Refrence From:
[image: RasPi-PinOut]

### STEP 3:

After That I Written The Following Code To Respective Rasberry Pi 4

`For MasterSPI.PY`

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)  # Open SPI bus 0, device 0

try:
    while True:
        send_data = [0x55, 0xAA, 0x33]  # Replace with the data you want to send
        received_data = spi.xfer2(send_data)
        print("Received:", received_data)
        time.sleep(12)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

spi.close()
```

`For SlaveSPI.PY`

```
import spidev

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)  # Open SPI bus 0, device 0
spi.mode = 0b01

try:
    while True:
        received_data = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00])  # Receive data from the master
        # Process received_data as needed
        print("Received:", received_data)
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

spi.close()
```

### STEP 4:

Runned This Master & Slave Script In Thier Respective Terminal Using `python3 MasterSPI.py` &`python3 SlaveSPI.py`

**NOTE**::*I Though After That MY Both Rasberry Pi 4 Will Communicate But On The Terminal It looks It Would Work But After Stopping MasterSPI Script Also on Slave Terminal It Was Showing Reieved 0,0,0 Only After Every 2 Seconds*

I am Not aware If i am doing this correctly or not But There Was No Online Tutorial To Do Such Was Availiable so i did What Found From Various Platform  , So If Some Body Wants To Give Suggestion About Tutorial Or The above Method Pls Feel Free To Comment Down

Thanks For Your Time

Comment: @Milliways Why it is difficult To Understand  I Made It Pretty Clear Every Step I did & Second thing is what is meant by MISO TO MISO Would Nor Work i tried this reference online https://radiostud.io/understanding-spi-in-raspberry-pi/

Comment: the refence in the diagrammes shows to connet MISO to MISO and MOSI to MOSI

Answer (score 1):

To understand SPI, you need a master and a slave. The Raspberry Pi is a master. You have two master which creates many problems. There are two clock running which are tied together and the output will be a mess. To make a Raspberry Pi a slave would require a lots of hacking, there is no default way to make it a slave.